# Search array in array (with float numbers ) with a given error

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to search for a specific array into another one. I was looking for PHP functions such as array_intersect() but this is not I really need.

Here is my trouble: I have `$array_1 = [5.3,5.0,6.7]` and $array_2 = `[5.0, 5.2,6.5,7.5,8.25]`. I need to search for $array_1 numbers into $array_2 with near values and they should be consecutive.

In this example, result error should be less than 0.5.
So, I should have: `$array_1` is found in `$array_2` because array 1 values are found in array 2 with given error.

- 5.3 - 5.0 = 0.3 (< 0.5)
- 5.0 - 5.2 = 0.2 (< 0.5)
- 6.7 - 6.5 = 0.2 (< 0.5)

Is there a PHP function that will search for $array_1 into $array_2 with a given eps. error? I was unable to find it on google.com

I hope my idea and trouble is clear for everyone that could help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: no. there isn't. you'll have to write one yourself. PHP is a toolbox. Don't reach into it and expect to pull out a fully constructed house. Pull out a hammer, screwdriver, saw, etc.. and build the house yourself.

Comment: @MarcB: Speaking of hammers: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-php-singularity/

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if there is something to help me. Not to reinvent bycicle.

Comment: to help you, there's all of PHP. But your need is pretty unusual so there's nothing premade to do it for you. You're basically looking for an inexact intersection match. That's not a thing people generally need out of a programming language. That said, there might be library *for* PHP that can do this, so hit up the PEAR network and see if someone wrote a more extensive array/list/whatever library. Otherwise, write it yourself (not really reinventing the bicycle. More like reinventing a particular sprocket)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your end goal, but this code might get you started:

```
    $array_1 = array (5.3,5.0,6.7);         #search for this
$array_2 = array (3.0, 4.4, 5.0, 5.2,6.5,7.5,8.25, 5.0, 5.2, 8.2, 5.0, 4.2, 4.1, 5.3,5.0,6.7);  #inside this

$err = 0.5;

$matchkeys= array();

$i = 0;
$tmp_match = '';
foreach ($array_2 as $k => $v) {        #crawl through array_2

        if (abs($v - $array_1[$i]) < $err) {
                echo "match at $k for $i \n";
                if ($i==0) {$tmp_match = $k;}
                $i++;           #if array one matches, then check next array 1 against next array 2
                if ($i == count($array_1)) {    #done matching array_1 ?
                        $matchkeys[] = $tmp_match;      //push first index value of compelte match to array
                        $tmp_match = '';
                        $i = 0;
                }
        }
        else {
                $tmp_match = '';
                $i=0;           #otherwise start over
        }
}

echo "\n\n found complete matches in array_2 at index: \n";
print_r($matchkeys);
```

Comment: Thank you! 
yesterday  night I was thinking about something similar. But I did not have enough time.